# ASP.NET core project is not loading in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to open a Solution file in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. Though is created in another PC with same Visual Studio Version.
I am getting this error -

My Project Directory\MyApp.UI\MyApp.UI.xproj : error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
My Project Directory\MyApp.UI\MyApp.UI.xproj

Any suggestions??

Comment: Do you have .net core installed? https://www.microsoft.com/net/download

Comment: Yes, Ruard. I realized this when i didn't see the ASP.NET Core Project Template in Visual Studio IDE. Trying with that, Possibly my problem should be resolved. Anyways Big Thanks for this prompt help :)

Comment: Hi Ruard, yes after installing ASP.NET Core it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if you create a new .NET Core app you need to have this file locally available - C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props. This file gets installed with VS 2015 Tooling for .NET Core. Meaning, in order to build ASP.NET CORE application on another workstation or server, you will need to install the VS 2015 Tooling which provides that file.  Browse to https://www.microsoft.com/net/core and click on the blue link to download ".NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2"  (or newer)
After downloading the install, try again. Should be a fairly basic NEXT->NEXT->NEXT install process.